# How to get the list of all component templates from the publications

Tags: 2011, c#

I want to get the list of all the component templates in .net assembly and push
those component templates to the DWT.

Got the publication webDav url but how to get the list of all component templates for time- being  hard-coded the component template web dav url.

Want to get this list of component templates at the different publications so want to avoid hard-coding. I want to get the list of the Component templates and populate the id and title of those

Comment: It's quite unclear what you are asking. Are you creating a programme in .NET to list your CTs? Then you'll be using the core service. What do you mean by "push... to the tbb"?

Answer (score 4):

Have you seen the GetComponentTemplateUris TBB in [this open source set of TBBs](http://sdltridionworld.com/community/2011_extensions/generic-2011-tbbs.aspx) on SDL Tridion World - if not, that will probably help you.